# Is it possible to scrape a series of nodes after certain text string?

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

**Short question:** I would like to scrape a series of html_nodes from a series of pages. The problem comes when those elements are inside a list which does not have any class nor id. I can't use XPATH neither because the position of the desired elements differ from one page to another depending on the previous information.

**Detailed information:**

- Sample page: https://www.fablabs.io/machines/othermill
- Target: I would like to scrape the name of all fablabs that are using
  that specific machine

The html code (fragment) looks like this:

```
<div class='heading'>Available at</div>
<ul class='list-unstyled'>
<li>
<img alt="The%20beach%20lab%20%28mobile%29" class="avatar tiny" src="...>
<a href="/labs/thebeachlab">The Beach Lab x Middle East</a>
</li>
<li>
<img alt="Default lab avatar" class="avatar tiny" src="...>
<a href="/labs/fabedcarolina">Fab Ed Carolina</a>
</li>
...

</ul>
```

Since there are no nested classes nor ids, my only option would be using Xpath like this:

```
fablabs = url %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul[3]/li/a') %>%
    html_text()
```

Unfortunately, although this would work for this page, will not work in other pages, as the position of this list changes from page to page depending on its previous content.

the only thing I know is that I would like to scrape something that is below the string `Available at`. Is there any way to achieve that in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using XPath [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis, for example :

```
//div[.="Available at"]/following-sibling::ul/li/a
```

brief explanation :

- **`//div[.="Available at"]`**: locate `div` elements where inner text equals 'Available at'
- **`/following-sibling::ul`**: then find all `ul` elements that are following-sibling of the `div`
- **`li/a`**: then from such `ul` elements, return grandchild `a` where parent is `li`

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and the explanation! Works like charm.